# R coding use of for loop

Tags: r

```
my_summary_COunt <- data %>%


 count(District_Name,Sex_of_the_participant, sort = TRUE) %>%



pivot_wider( names_from=Sex_of_the_participant, values_from=n )
```

I have large data set  256385*568 and I want to use the above code but in a loop so I don't have to put y variable i.e Sex_of_the_participant again.

something like this

```
    my_range= 9:50
    for (i in my_range) { 

    my_summary_COunt_[i] <- data %>%

   count(District_Name,data[i], sort = TRUE) %>%

   pivot_wider( data[i], values_from=n )}
```

but this is not working

Comment: From the data in pictures one can guess that you want to pivot your data from long format to wide format and there is an abundance of ways to do that in R. `pivot_wider` in the package `tidy` is the first that came to my mind and Sirius' answer using that popped up while I was writing this. However, do not make your questions dependent on links, just post the examples on this site. Links will eventually not work anymore. Also, please concern yourself with what we call a minimal verifiable reproducible example for better questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In short: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical pivot_wider situation:

```r
library(tidyr)
your.data %>% pivot_wider( names_from=District_Name, values_from=n )
```